# Glassfish installation issue on Mac

Tags: java, eclipse, web-services, glassfish, glassfish-4

I was trying to install it through Eclipse EE IDE. It finished downloading, but wouldn't install.

I have seen a bunch of questions about this on SE, but it's either a different OS, or a different problem, so couldn't find any solution yet.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Have you already extracted GlassFish to a location on your Mac? The dialog in the image there is the Eclipse dialog to specify *where an existing GlassFish is* - it will not install anything there.

Try these steps:

1. Download the GlassFish Full profile ZIP from here:
   https://glassfish.java.net/download.html
2. Extract it to some directory, e.g.:
   `/Users/Sartaj/Programs/GlassFish`
3. Open the dialog in your screenshot above and choose the directory where you extracted it